# How do I retrieve a value from a property using Active Directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to write a code that retrieves a user's email from the LDAP server. The user's email is in the 'mail' property, however, everytime I run it, the email returns "System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection" instead of the user's email. Here is my code:

```
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
        {        
            string server = "hello.world.com:389";
            string email = null;

            DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + server + "/DC=hello,DC=world,DC=com");
            DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);
            dSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            dSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=users)(cn=" + lanID + "))";
            dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

            SearchResult result = dSearch.FindOne();

            if (result != null)
            {
                email = result.Properties["mail"].ToString();
                return email;
            }
            else return email = null;
        }
```

The code takes a user's employee id (lanID) and returns that userID's email (the value under 'mail' property). How should I do so I don't get System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection but an actual email?

Comment: result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString()

Comment: Perfect, worked great.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`SearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.getdirectoryentry(v=vs.110).aspx) Method to get the directory entry which corresponds to this SearchResult.

> Retrieves the DirectoryEntry that corresponds to the SearchResult from
>   the Active Directory Domain Services hierarchy. **Use GetDirectoryEntry when you want to look at the live entry** instead of the entry that was returned through DirectorySearcher, or when you want to invoke a method on the object that was returned.
>   --emphasis mine.

Use the below code:

```
DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
string distinguishedName = user.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
(String)user.Properties["mail"][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This means you are trying to convert an entire object to a string.

Change

```
email = result.Properties["mail"].ToString();
```

To this

```
email = result.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting this message:
'ResultPropertyValueCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extenstion method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'ResultPropertyValueCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @JKang - You may like to check my answer and see if it helps. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
email = result.getdirectoryentry.properties("mail").value
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).